# Css menu assistance, dropdown issue

Tags: html, css

Ok hey guys.
So what I try to acheive is to have a menu in the topnav of my site and when hovring the mouse over to show some stuff in a list under it.

so far I'm working on local on a test html file until I get it working.
so what i got so far is this menu:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Notifications</a>
    <ul>
        <li id="foot-notify-954>
            <a href="#" class="delete" onclick="deleteNotification('Delete this item?', 954);return false;">X</a><a href="http://test.com/testing">testing</a> left a comment for your <a href="http://test.com/member/174/blog/view/28/">blog</a> 22 hours ago
        </li>
        <li id="foot-notify-953>
            <a href="#" class="delete" onclick="deleteNotification('Delete this item?', 953);return false;">X</a>
            <p><a href="http://test.com/testing">testing</a> left a comment for your <a href="http://test.com/member/174/blog/view/28/">blog</a> <span>22 hours ago</span></p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and my css code:

```
ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
li ul { display: none }
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #2C5463;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover { background: #617F8A }
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a { background: #617F8A }
li:hover li a:hover { background: #95A9B1 }
```

I think the problem is that I'm having more than 1 `<a>` hyperlink inside the notifications `<li>`
id like each li notification to show in 1 line, as in the format, the X button at the start to remove it then the notification itself.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to check the html syntax:

list should looks like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp):

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li><a href='#'>Milk</a></li>
</ul>
```

This tool helps you find the errors (red highlighted):
http://jsbin.com/emowir/1/edit

---

Here is your example:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <!-- type 1: NOT drop down-->
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>

 <!--type 2: drop down-->
  <li><a href="">About Us</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">The Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="">History</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Vision</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What would you like to insert and where?

Comment: Code was taken from here
https://www.servage.net/blog/2009/03/20/create-a-cool-css-based-drop-down-menu/

wich works perfect.. but even in their code if you add another a hyperlink in the list it breaks it

Comment: Basically the Home link will act asa the on hover efect..so when hovered, under it will show the notifications i got.something like this
the <li><a href="">The Team</a></li> rows will hold my notification messages.
it will become something like
`<li><a href="#" class="delete" onclick="deleteNotification('Delete this item?', 954);return false;">X</a><a href="http://test.com/testing">testing</a> left a comment for your <a href="http://test.com/member/174/blog/view/28/">blog</a> 22 hours ago</a>`

Comment: could you provide a draft image?

Comment: my notifcations will go in the dropdown..as i had it in original post works..but i think because i have more than i <a> tag in the li items its not showing them on 1 single line

Comment: Ok go here
http://jsbin.com/emowir/3/edit
Notifications menu is mine, About us is from the original code i got from the web

Comment: also, need it to be a general code, cause i will have most likely more than 2 notifications to show

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16211/discussion-between-misulicus-and-2astalavista)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem does seem to be bad code formatting. [This is a clean and edited version of your code.](http://jsbin.com/emowir/11/edit) The code "breaking" is an issue of CSS formatting. Using inline-blocks instead of blocks helps get things lined up properly, and shifting the background style to the `<li>` rather than the `<a>` makes it look better.

Comment: Oh yes thank you...i`l test it now on the live website to see if they show up properly..wil keep u updated in a bit

Comment: one more thing, the css u made, what do i have to change/add to it to make sure it applies only to that <ul id="menu"> ? Because i have to add it inside a global css file for the whole site

Comment: Add `ul#menu` before each of the CSS declarations (or change the root `ul` in the declaration to `ul#menu`). Such as http://jsbin.com/emowir/13/edit

Comment: hey is there i can chat with ya ? would be grete if u can assist me on the live site

Comment: I have plenty of my own work to do - I don't have time to walk you through working on your site. Trial and error is how the best of us learn.

Comment: thanks for the reply..but i got no clue how to work with css :(

Comment: Plenty of sites that'll teach you. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) may not be the best site, but it has tutorials you can use. Or, find a site look you like and borrow the CSS from it, playing around with it until it looks like how you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the following:

```
ul li a {
    display: block;
```

This makes every link you insert into the list a block. Try start to float things like in this example I made from your code, http://jsfiddle.net/xN8sc/1/